# Why $("input:radio") is not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

**I can highlight radio button !! Why ?**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
     $("input:radio").css('border','1px solid red');
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.a { color: Navy; }
.b { color: Maroon; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type='radio' checked='checked'>Male
<input type='radio>Female
</form>
</body>
```

I saw many codes in stackoverflow like this used by people

Comment: Do not quote document `$(document)` not `$("document")`

Comment: `ready` function doesn't care.

Comment: the selector is just fine.... what you are trying to do is the problem

Comment: I dont think that, we can apply border to radio button like this

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

instead of

```
 $("document").ready(function() {
```